# Why do the crew in Timeless worry about tracking quickly and recharge times etc?

Tags: plot-explanation, timeless

Other than to make the action move along, I can't remember there being an in-show/canon explanation for something they seem to say (a variation of) every episode of *Timeless*:

> The mothership has just jumped, track it quickly, you guys prep for launch.

Why on earth do they need to hurry? They're literally about to use a time machine! So the mothership landed at 6am on Nov 9th 185x, land at 5:59am a mile away and off you go? Why do you need to hurry in the present?

The people I'm watching with had a couple of ideas:

- There's a risk that Flynn will change the timeline so much that you don't exist anymore (but surely he's already done that 100 years ago?)
- You can only go back years not days/hours
- You always travel back to the same time of day on a different date
- If you go back to before he lands he might choose not to land

Without an explanation though it just seems daft.

Comment: With most time travel stories, the answer is some variation on ["wibbly-wobbly timey-wimey stuff"](https://youtu.be/mDsN5lWLKU0?t=1m10s).

Answer (score 1):

I always got the impression that they were worried about changes to the timeline. They don't know what Flynn had planned for whatever location/time he was traveling too, so they had to find him and get to that spot as quickly as possible to stop him from enacting that plan.

If he was able to change something before they got there, they could either a) leave the known present but arrive at an unknown future, or b) have the known present change due to the timeline adjusting and not be aware of what they were trying to do or who they were trying to stop.